# MSMQ messages disappear when they get to remote server

Tags: msmq, system.messaging

I have to create a **MSMQ** messaging mechanism between two servers in the same domain, *SenderServer* (MS Server 2012) and *ReceiverServer* (MS Server 2008 R2).

I created a private, transactional queue in *ReceiverServer* `.\private$\receiver`, I gave receive (and peek) message rights to system and administrators.

I then created a client application that creates and forwards messages to the queue by using the following code:

```
MessageQueue queue = new queue("FormatName:Direct=OS:ReceiverServer\private$\receiver");
Message message = new Message();
message.Body = "myMessage";

using (MessageQueueTransaction tx = new MessageQueueTransaction())
{
  tx.Begin();
  queue.Send(message, "myLabel", tx);
  tx.Commit();
}
```

Before deploying the application, I tested it from my machine (Windows 7) that correctly creates an outgoing queue `Direct=OS:ReceiverServer\private$\receiver` with `State:Connected` and `Connection History:Connection is ready to transfer messages`. 
The messages are correctly sent to the *ReceiverServer* and placed in the `\private$\receiver` queue. The `End2End log` of the *ReceiverServer* for every message logs two events:

1. Message came over network (EventId: 4)
2. Message with `ID CN=msmq, CN=[mymachinename], CN=Computers, DC=[domain], DC=[other]` was put into queue `ReceiverServer\private$\receiver` (EventId: 1)

Then I used the client application from within the *SenderServer* using the same code. The server correctly creates an outgoing queue `Direct=OS:ReceiverServer\private$\receiver` with `State:Connected` and `Connection History:Connection is ready to transfer messages`, I can see the message queuing up and be sent but I do not receive them in the remote *ReceiverServer* queue `.\private$\receiver`. If I check the *End2End event log* of the *ReceiverServer* I just see the first message (Message came over network (EventId: 4)) but the message is not placed in the queue.

I turned off firewalls from both machines, changed the authorization settings for the queue and tried the following endpoint for the queues:

- `FormatName:Direct=OS:[IPv6 address]\private$\receiver`
- `FormatName:Direct=TCP:ReceiverServer\private$\receiver`
- `FormatName:Direct=TCP:[IPv6 address]\private$\receiver`

With no luck. The troubleshooting process and the documentation from Microsoft are really general and simplistic, therefore I decided to ask here because for me is a dead end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sender domain account needs to have the following permissions on the remote queue: Send, Get Permissions, Get Properties

Are these machines on the same domain? If not you may need to grant the above permissions to the local user called ANONYMOUS LOGON

Comment: You effectively nailed it, thanks! But yet it does not explain why it was working from my Windows 7 machine...

Comment: Ok spotted why. The message were sent from my machine using my account which had the correct permissions in the Receiver queue :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem and spend a few hours resolving it, so I wanted to post an answer to save others who may fall into the same trap I did.

When the queue was created on the remote server, it was mistakenly created as a transactional queue. However the code that was posting the messages was calling send without the transaction parameter. I could see the message at the sending workstation, but once it hit the destination server, it would disappear without any logging, journaling, or events to help determine why.

Once I identified the problem, I recreated the Queue as a non-transactional queue, and the issue was fixed.